# Logrotate seemingly freeing system memory

Tags: linux, erlang, logrotate

We have a bit of a mystery on our hands. We are seeing what appears to be a memory leak in one of our Erlang systems. System memory utilization slowly, but steadily, increases over time. Then, when our logrotate job for that apps system logs runs we see a sudden drop in memory utilization that then starts slowly climbing again. Does anybody have any clue as to what could be causing this behavior? We are at a complete loss.

Comment: can it be pending actions with files which are terminated and cleaned up when the VM and logrotate enter in conflict?

Comment: @Pascal If I understand your question correctly, I'm not sure what other actions would be pending. I initially thought it could be the erlang mailbox filling-up in our asynchronous logging module. But, I do not see this when using observer to monitor the application.

Comment: I was thinking about read or write accesses to file locking memory in the VM and which could be freed later - so the memory leak appears from the OS but not in the erlang processes themselves.

Comment: How are you measuring memory usage for that system and does it include OS buffers? With the given information it could be the OS filesystem cache dropping once the file is rotated.

Comment: We're seeing something similar. Are you running in a Docker, by any chance?